# Гонение на кого-то или гонение кого-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: гонение на кого-то или гонение кого-то? Например: гонение церкви или гонение на церковь.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от контекста.

"Гонение церкви" - это когда церковь преследует еретика (к примеру).

"Гонение на церковь" - еретик (власть, партия) преследуют церковь.

[**ГОНЕНИЕ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x). Притеснение, преследование, постоянные нападки на кого-, что-л. *Переносить, терпеть гонения. Подвергнуться гонению. Г. на христиан. Г. на литературу. Г. со стороны государства. **Гонения судьбы*** (о жизненных невзгодах, неудачах).

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее: **гонение на церковь.** В этом случае не возникает неясностей на тему, кто кого  "гонит", к тому же такое выражение воспринимается как общая политика власти по отношению **к различным институтам** церкви (в виде ограничений, репрессий, отрицания ценностей и т.д.).

А вообще говоря, существуют **три варианта ** с разным смыслом или разными смысловыми оттенками:

**Вариант 1. Гонение кого-то/чего-то** (конкретное/адресное воздействие, беспредложный Р.п.)

Некрасов подписывает обращение к руководству страны, призывающее прекратить **гонение инакомыслящих**. [Владимир Потресов. Возвращения Некрасова (2004)].  Темы, поднимаемые им, в основном общего морального свойства: печальная судьба ума и бедности, пышное, разгульное житье глупости, невежество в верхах, **гонение науки.**

**Вариант 2. Гонение на кого-то/что-то** (общая направленность воздействия, В.п., предлог НА)

В сорок восьмом году под маркой борьбы с космополитизмом началось **гонение на всё иностранное**. [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

**Вариант 3. Гонение (= со стороны)  кого-то/чего-то** (беспредложный Р.п.)

И с тех пор ни **гонение судьбы,** ни бедность, ни нужда, ни косые взгляды аристократической родни не могли уже его свернуть с любимого, избранного им пути. [М. Ф. Каменская. Воспоминания (1894)]. Их на бунт влечет, а отсюда гонение **власти** на них. [Максим Горький. Дело Артамоновых (1924-1925)].